# How to prevent tab selection on ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I have two tabs with ngx-bootstrap like bellow, and I want to programatically stop tab functionality rom working:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="First">Tab 1 content</tab>
    <tab heading="Second">Tab 2 content</tab>
</tabset>

<label>Edit in progress: </label>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isTabSwitchEnabled">
```

Basically, if I have a dirty form in, say, **Tab 1**, I want to popup a "Discard changes?" dialog before allowing the user to "navigate" to **Tab 2**. I see nothing on the ngx-bootstrap [tabs API](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs) that I could use.

I have an example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tabs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) where I tried working with `[disabled]` on tabs, and it works partways, but not fully, because I cannot set the tab programatically active (or I don't know how):

```
export class MyComponent  {
  disableSwitching: boolean;
  @ViewChild('tabset') tabset: TabsetComponent;
  @ViewChild('first') first: TabDirective;
  @ViewChild('second') second: TabDirective;

  confirmTabSwitch($event) {
    if (this.disableSwitching) {
      const confirm = window.confirm('Discard changes and switch tab?');
      if (confirm) {
        this.disableSwitching = false;
        this.second.active = true;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The `this.second.active = true` doesn't switch to the new tab, only marks it active. The same if I try with `this.tabset.tabs[index].active = true;`.

Is there a way to have this functionality? Enable and disable switching tabs? Ideally bind it to a router too (but I definitely need programatic access).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a working stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tabs-rs832l?file=app/app.component.ts

The thing here is that `select` event emits before tabset sets `active` property of all other tabs to `false` so you need to wrap the code that selects a tab in a `setTimeout` or something like that. This will set the active tab after all internal operations of the tabset.

*Edit*: as the OP says, at current (ngx-bootstrap@2.0.2) the workaround is to find the matching element on the tabset component and activate:

```
confirmTabSwitch($event) {
  if (this.disableSwitching) {
    const confirm = window.confirm('Discard changes and switch tab?');
    if (confirm) {
      this.disableSwitching = false;
      const liArr = Array.from(this.tabsetEl.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('ul li'));
      let tabIndex;
      liArr.forEach((li, i) => {
        if(li.contains($event.target)) {
          tabIndex = i;
        }
      });
      setTimeout(() => this.tabset.tabs[tabIndex].active = true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was somewhat useful to know, but I still have a bit of a problem with this demo: Click on tab 2. Then check the checkbox. Then click tab 1 again, and confirm with "OK". It won't switch back to 1.

Comment: There's a hardcode in the example below, just for demonstration purposes. A dynamic version of that would look somewhat like that https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tabs-dfvqln?file=app/app.component.ts . This implementation is messy but it's ok as a workaround. We'll provide an API for preventing tab select in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is :

```
@ViewChild('first') first: TabDirective;
```

Not pointing to the `TabDirective` but just native `ElementRef` , so `this.second.active = true;` will not make `TabDirective` active.

You can achevie that simply using `this.tabset.tabs[index].active = true;`

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-tabs-pgqjk1)**

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't using ElementRef, you can check in the code in the question and on the linked Stackblitz. Also, your working demo link doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I know but some how , if you will check it returns the `ElementRef` and not `TabDirective` , coz of that active code is not working.